# Set constraints in Xcode so NSView will resize if content width increases

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, constraints

I have a NSView which contains a NSTextField.
I want to set constraints so that the view width will increase if the NSTextField content reaches the view size.

When setting a leading constraint the NSTextField width will increase if the text contains longer text but I cannot get the NSView to resize.

What do I miss here?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to set a constraint for the vertical axis and if you want to keep the text inside the box, you need to set the trailing constraint.

Hope this helps you :)